# Unable to get canvas

Tags: html, canvas

I can't see why this code gives me an error line 11

```
 if (canvas.getContext) {...

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Peripheral vision checker</title>

  <script type="application/javascript">

    function draw() { if (canvas.getContext) {
      const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
      if (canvas.getContext) {
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        function getRandomInt(max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
        }
        var x = 1000;//will be equal to window height
        var y = 100;//will be equal to window width
        ctx.arc(getRandomInt(x), getRandomInt(y), 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);

        console.log(getRandomInt(x) + " " + getRandomInt(y));//just temporary to see they work

        ctx.fill();
    }

  }

  </script>
 </head>
 <h1>Peripheral vision checker</h1>
 <body onload="draw();">
   <canvas id="canvas></canvas>
 </body>
</html>
```

There is no CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You're never actually trying to get it.

In your code you've got this line. The first thing it does it check if `canvas` is not null, and if the function getContext is available. The following line
sets `canvas`. It will always fail on that first check.

```
function draw() { if (canvas.getContext) {
```

Also noteworthy, in the HTML there's a missing quote causing your canvas' ID to be up for misinterpretation.

```
<canvas id="canvas></canvas>
```

Corrected code

```js
function draw() {
  const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  if (ctx) {
    function getRandomInt(max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
    }
    var x = 100; //will be equal to window height
    var y = 100; //will be equal to window width
    ctx.arc(getRandomInt(x), getRandomInt(y), 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI, 0);

    console.log(getRandomInt(x) + " " + getRandomInt(y)); //just temporary to see they work
    ctx.fillColor = "black";


    ctx.fill();
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="draw();">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
```